# Symfony 3.4 entity extra columns in controller response

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4

I have this entity:

```
<?php
//namespace
//use ...
class Guide
{
    private $id;
    //private ...

    //getters
    //setters
}
?>
```

In a controller I use the entity manager to retrieve the data of this entity.

```
$guides= $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Guide')
        ->findAll();
```

My entity has 4 parameters: id, name, pages, author.
Is there any way to add two extra parameters, that aren´t in the class declaration and I don´t want in the database, if the entity manager returns for example 3 rows, I want o add two extra values to each row and return the data, for example add two boolean values: ok => true, warning => false.

I have tried this:

```
foreach($guides as $guide){
    $guide->ok=true;
    $guide->warning=false;
}
```

If I dump $guides, I see the two parameters like this:

```
-id:1
-name:'Guide 1'
-pages:12
-author:'John'
+"ok":true
+"warning":false
```

But when I use this to send a response:

```
return new Response($serializer->serialize($guides, 'json'));
```

The two extra parameters aren´t in the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a property to entity and do not tag it as a ORM\Column eg:

```
<?php
//...

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="guides")
 */
class Guide
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
     /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string")
     */
    private $name;
    public $myAdditionalProperty;
//...
```

And then set it in your controller:

```
foreach($guides as $guide){
    $guide->myAdditionalProperty = "my amazing value";
}
```

Then you can serialize your data without having additional column in your table